# Run shell script/commands when starting flask development server

Tags: python, shell, reactjs, flask

I have a web app written in reactjs with a flask backend. As I currently have the project set up, the reactjs app is nested within the flask app and I use symlinks to place the compiled `bundle.js` file in its proper place (the file containing my js). So my project looks something like this:

```
├── app.py
├── js
│   └── bundle.js -> reactapp/public/bundle.js
├── reactapp
│   └── public
│       └── bundle.js
└── templates
```

This works fine but every time I change anything in my react app I need to have webpack rebuild my bundle.js manually. I want to know if there is someway to have `npm run build` called or execute a shell script every time `flask run` is called to start the dev server so `bundle.js` is always up to date. Is this possible? Alternatively, is there some best practice for using flask+react that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am certainly no React.js dev, but for such cases I usually just write a quick bash wrapper script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run build && flask run
```

That way Flask will only run if the NPM build completed successfully.
Hope this helps, somehow.